# GCP predefines IAM roles per Project and Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to structure GCP access per folder so folder users can only have project viewer within folder and every project created within the folder should allow only specific resource usage in the project for the team that has access to folder.

I managed to create the folder part, projects will be created over terraform and now I have a blocker how to do per project iam permissions with predefined roles. Let's say I have a group that need to work on project X created by terraform and that group will use Cloud SQL, Compute Engine, Network management. So ideally I would create [google_project_iam_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding) in TF where members would be be that group and role would contain list of predefined IAM roles for those resources. But that is not possible to do, I need guidance how to achieve this.

```
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "km-role" {
  role_id     = "KnowledgeManagementRole"
  title       = "Knowledge Management Custom Role"
  description = "Test role for KM"
  permissions = [
    "compute.*",
    "networkmanagement.*",
    "resourcemanager.projects.get",
    "resourcemanager.projects.list",
    "serviceusage.quotas.get",
    "serviceusage.services.get",
    "serviceusage.services.list",
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately there is no support for `*` so in this case I would have to write 30+ computer permissions. You also can't use predefined roles as a list in custom iam role :/.

Comment: It is possible to do a user group binding using `google_project_iam_binding`, maybe I'm not fully understanding your situation,  are you having problems creating the custom role or what is the issue that is not allowing you to complete this step?

Comment: The problem is permission list. For example If I wanted to add all computer permissions, there are over 40 of them and I need to list all of them in the aim_custom_role. `google_project_iam_binding` supports only ONE permission in the code. You can't define a list of permissions there - that's the problem. Only way I know how to overcome that is to use `iam_custom_role` but then you need to put all possible permissions that are part of `computer.*` for example since `*` in expression is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the GCP Custom role [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles), looks like there's no way to create a custom role other than adding exactly all the permissions that you want the role to have, this seems to be a way to encourage the granularity of your custom roles and avoid possible security incidents that can be caused by adding Basic/Predefined roles to a custom one.

I found that there's an open Feature Request in Public Issue Tracker to be able to add predefined roles to a custom role:

[[FR] Be able to add pre-defined roles to a custom role](https://issuetracker.google.com/130752163)

If you “star” the request you will receive notifications for any important updates and keep track of its progress.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'll look into service account and impersonation permissions. Not sure if that's good way to do it...

Comment: I'm not sure how are you planning to implement service accounts and impersonation permissions, but I think that you'll end up adding just one more step to the process as the Service Account will need the custom role as well.